# How to convert int year to date and display it as century SQL Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

how can I convert int like '1984' to date and display it as century SQL Oracle?

Comment: What date is 1984? (1984 had 366 different dates.) And how do you want to display it?`

Comment: I make small project of liblary to my University. I have colum 'date of publication' in int 'yyyy' format. Now I want to create view that will change this int to century and will group all books by it.

Comment: And the expected result for 1984 is?

Comment: For example year 1984 will be displayed as 
|century|
   20

Comment: `ceil(1984 / 100)` will return 20.

Comment: How do you know which century a year belongs to?

Comment: The 21st century began on January 1, 2001 so 2000 is still 20 century. His solution is correct.

Comment: I was wrong on my earlier comment, 1900 and 2000 belong to 19th and 20th centuries. Use CC in the to_char to convert a date to a century: select to_char(sysdate, 'CC') from dual;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the column is a date/time or timestamp:

```
select to_char(columnname, 'CC') as century from tablename;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 'century', ceil(yearcolumn / 100) from tablename
```